# How to get access to UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate from with NSObject

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have a class

```
 final class Restaurant{...

      class func makeNewRestaurant{...
         // this makes instance of Restaurant
      }
}
```

In this class, which is an instance of RestaurantMO (managedobject) I have a class method makeNewRestaurant which makes a new instance of Restaurant.

I also want a class method saveNewRestaurant(Restaurant:aRestaurant) which will save the Restaurant to persistentContainer.viewContext (i.e., Core Data). When I try the following I get the following error.

```
appDelegate = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
```

error "Use of unresolved identifier UIApplication". I am thinking Restaurant shouldn't have access to AppDelegate. So then how do I get access to persistentContainer.viewContext, from within Restaurant, and save the instance from my class method saveNewRestaurant?

Comment: Aren’t you missing a `import UIKit` in this file?

Comment: No. That worked, but should I be importing UIKit into an NSObject? It isn't for display?

Comment: @jdog The class `UIApplication` is defined in the module UIKit (The "UI" prefix in "UIApplication" is a big give away ;) ). UIKit is more than just "display": it basically manages all platform specific code in iOS; for example: the responder chain, the application object, and (yes) the view hierarchy.

Comment: The analogue functionality on macOs is handled by **AppKit**. Confusingly, AppKit classes have names prefixed with "NS", the same as those in the Foundation framework. When Apple developed iPhone OS, they wisely chose a separate prefix for the classes in the UI framework (UIKit). Foundation is largely the same on both platforms I believe.